# Access Transparent Router's Web Interface

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, wireless-router, tomato

A picture I made in paint is shown below which shows how my network is setup. The main router goes out to the internet. I connected a 2nd router to the main router in order to support older devices that use wireless B & G only. The router is running Tomato firmware (found [here](http://www.polarcloud.com/tomato))

I wanted my main router to act as the only DHCP server, so I disabled the one in the secondary router and now all of the devices that are connected to the 2nd router are accessing the main network and the main router.

The problem is that I now cannot access the 2nd router web interface anymore, **even though I gave it a different IP address than the main router.** Any ideas on how I can access both?

**LAYOUT OF NETWORK:**

[image]

**EDIT:** I was able to access it by manually assigning a static IP to my PC that is attached to the 2nd router. Is there a faster method than having to do this every time I need to change a setting?

Comment: not without some kind of application gateway. Your configuration really isn't right though. unless you have configured router 2 as a bridge, it's lan side clients really should be in a different IP network, and dhcp handled by a device on that network. Also note that you have your own networks on both sides of router2, which is not normal for most home-grade firewall-routers. some allow you to set a configuration that disables management access from the wan, and those that don't usually don't allow wan-side management at all.

Comment: @FrankThomas I configured the 2nd router such that it does not assign any IP addresses and all of the devices connected to it will get an IP address from the main router. That's what I was aiming for since I didn't want to create a LAN within a LAN.
I did not understand what you meant by networks on both sides of router2 and what wan-side management has to do with it. Can you please explain?
Thanks

Comment: router2 is connected to two networks, its lan, and its WAN, which is the network Router1 defines, unless you have configured Router2 to be a bridge, not a router. since you want to connect to the web management page on router2, if it only allows lan-side management, you would have to be connected to the LAN side of the router to access the page. So, is Router2 configured as a Bridge, or as a Router?

Comment: @FrankThomas the second router is set up as an access point, so I'm guessing that means it's set up as a router? If I change it to bridge mode, what would the benefits be?

Comment: ahh, ok, if its operating as an AP, it is not acting as a router.

Comment: @FrankThomas so I'm guessing that means that my setup is correct? Also, what about accessing the Web interface. Is there am easier way than to manually assign an IP address to a PC that is connected to the 2nd router?

Comment: see thats the thing, you shouldn't need to change your IP at all, if the router is in AP mode, since it is part of your network. Is your uplink plugged into the LAN or WAN port? all the addresses are on the same network, right? like 192.168.55.x?

Comment: @FrankThomas Yes, all addresses are on the same network. I disabled the DHCP on the 2nd router and used the IP address of the main router as the gateway for the 2nd router. I also converted the WAN port on the 2nd router into a LAN port since it only works on LAN ports. Now since you mentioned it, I had to give my 2nd router an IP address for the Web interface. I chose 192.168.2.1 and my main is on 192.168.1.1. Could that be the problem? Should I choose something else for the 2nd router?

Comment: yes that is exactly the problem. since your router is an AP now, and cannot route, its addressess must be on the .1.x subnet.

Comment: @FrankThomas so you're saying I should go and change the IP address I assigned manually to the 2nd router to be something within the .1.x subnet? That will fix the problem and allow me to access the web interface?

Comment: that's the idea. its just a node on your network now, not a router.